# Active Directory Password without SSL java

Tags: java, active-directory

When I want to establish the connection with ssl of active directory it gives me this error I do not know that it can be.

I already have the certificate in the java and glassfish store.

Problem creating object: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: hostname of the server '172.18.141.100' does not match the hostname in the server's certificate.

This is a piece of code

```html
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        String user = "siampuser";
        String adminPassword = "S14mpad";
        String userName = "CN=" + primerNombre + ' ' + primerApellido + "," + "OU=testunit3,DC=mp,DC=gob,DC=gt";
        String groupName = "CN=Configuration,OU=testunit3,DC=mp,DC=gob,DC=gt";


        env.put(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        env.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, user + "@" + domain);
        env.put(javax.naming.Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, adminPassword);
        env.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapHost);

        try {
            LdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

            Attributes attrs = new BasicAttributes(true);
            attrs.put("objectClass", "user");
            attrs.put("samAccountName", usuario);
            attrs.put("givenName", primerNombre + ' ' + segundoNombre);
            attrs.put("sn", primerApellido + ' ' + segundoApellido);
            attrs.put("cn", primerNombre + ' ' + primerApellido);
            attrs.put("description", puesto);
            attrs.put("physicalDeliveryOfficeName", dependencia + ' ' + departamento);
            attrs.put("telephoneNumber", fechaNacimiento + '/' + dpi + '/' + nit);
            attrs.put("mail", usuario + "@mp.gob.gt");
            attrs.put("title", puesto);
            attrs.put("department", dependencia);
            if (nip != null) {
                attrs.put("wWWHomePage", nip.toString());
                //attrs.put("st", nip.toString());
            }

            int UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE = 0x0002;
            int UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD = 0x0020;
            int UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE = 0x0040;
            int UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT = 0x0200;
            int UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = 0x10000;
            int UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED = 0x800000;

            attrs.put("userAccountControl", Integer.toString(UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT + UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD + UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED + UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE));
            javax.naming.Context result = ctx.createSubcontext(userName, attrs);
            System.out.println("usuario creado : " + userName);

            StartTlsResponse tls = (StartTlsResponse) ctx.extendedOperation(new StartTlsRequest());
            SSLSession session = tls.negotiate();
            //tls.negotiate();

            ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[2];
            String newQuotedPassword = "\"" + password + "\"";
            byte[] newUnicodePassword = newQuotedPassword.getBytes("UTF-16LE");

            mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", newUnicodePassword));
            mods[1] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("userAccountControl", Integer.toString(UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT + UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED)));
            //mods[1] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("userAccountControl", Integer.toString(UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT + UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD)));
            // Perform the update
            ctx.modifyAttributes(userName, mods);
            System.out.println("Set password & updated userccountControl");

            //now add the user to a group.
            try {
                ModificationItem member[] = new ModificationItem[1];
                member[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.ADD_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("member", userName));

                ctx.modifyAttributes(groupName, member);
                System.out.println("Usuario agregado a la ou: " + groupName);

            } catch (NamingException e) {
                System.err.println("Error al agregar el usario a la ou: " + e);
                return new Response("Error al agregar el usario a la ou: " + e, ResponseStatus.ERROR);
            }

            tls.close();
            ctx.close();

            //System.out.println("usuario crearo existosamente: " + userName);
            return new Response("usuario crearo existosamente: " + userName, ResponseStatus.OK_QUERY);

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al crear el usuario: " + e);
            return new Response("Error al crear el usuario: " + e, ResponseStatus.ERROR);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem creating object: " + e);
        }
        return null;
```

Comment: A X.509 certificate is usually tied to hostname, so i assume you try to connect to your LDAP server with its IP-Adress

Comment: But then it would have to generate the certificate with the hostname?